# Hangman.java replace blank with right letters guessed

Tags: java

I want my hangman game to be able to replace the blanks " _ " with the right letters in the word.

This is how my program looks like atm:

```
package hängagubbe;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class hangdamang {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Engine
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner ord = new Scanner(new File("c:/words.txt"));        
        int gissningar = 0;
        String blanks = "";
        String guessword;
        String rightLetters = "";
        String guess;
        // Arraylist, här sparas alla ord
        ArrayList<String> arswag = new ArrayList<String>();
        // while loop, tar ord från words.txt och lägger till arraylisten.
        while(ord.hasNext()) {
            arswag.add(ord.nextLine());
        }
        //Väljer ett random ord i arraylisten.
        Collections.shuffle(arswag);
        String pickWord = arswag.get(0);
        System.out.println(pickWord);
        int w=pickWord.length();
        //Delar det random valda ordet till endast bokstaver till arrayen
        String [] splitword = pickWord.split("");
        //
        for(int i = 1; i <= pickWord.length(); i++){
            blanks +="-";
            }

        //Riktiga spelet:
        System.out.println("Välkommen till mitt hänga gubbe spel.");
        System.out.println("Längden på ordet du ska gissa är: " + w);
        System.out.println(blanks);
        do{ 
            System.out.println("\n" + "Skriv en bokstav för att gissa ordet.");
            System.out.println("Antal gissningar du gjort:" + gissningar);
            gissningar++;
            guess = input.next();
           for(int y=1; y < splitword.length; y++) {
            if (guess.equals(splitword[y])) {
                 System.out.print(guess );

            }
             else
                 System.out.print(" _ ");
           }
      } while (true);

}
}
```

As you can see, I made so far that you can guess letters and when the word for example test, and you guess s, it will say this:

```
_ _ s _
```

But then when you guess again and do T, it says:

```
t _ _ t
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Just as a comment: as a naming convention in java, class names are written in CamelCase: eg `HangmanGame`. If you are looking for a large list of english words, this might be interesting for you: http://zyzzyva.net/wordlists.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some fun playing with your code, this is what I got. I wrote some notes here and there, hope it gives you a start :)

```
// NOTE: java naming convntion: capital class names
// complete documentation see here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html
public class Hangdamang {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Engine
        // NOTE: it is c-style to declare all needed variables in top of the method
        // in java you can declare them close to where you need them. Provides better readability at no costs.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner ord = new Scanner(new File("words.txt")); // for example zyzzyva.net/wordlists.shtml        
        int gissningar = 0;
        // Arraylist, här sparas alla ord
        ArrayList<String> arswag = new ArrayList<String>();
        // while loop, tar ord från words.txt och lägger till arraylisten.
        while(ord.hasNext()) {
            arswag.add(ord.nextLine());
        }
        //Väljer ett random ord i arraylisten.
        Collections.shuffle(arswag);
        String pickWord = arswag.get(0).split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(pickWord);

        // hold a list of not yet guessed letters 
        List<Character> unknownLetters = new LinkedList<Character>(); // NOTE: you could as well use ArrayList
        for(Character c = 'a'; c<='z'; c++)
            unknownLetters.add(c);

        //Riktiga spelet:
        System.out.println("Välkommen till mitt hänga gubbe spel.");
        System.out.println("Längden på ordet du ska gissa är: " + pickWord.length());
        String guess="";
        String showWord="";
        while(!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(pickWord) && !showWord.equalsIgnoreCase(pickWord)) {

            System.out.println(showWord);

            System.out.println("\n" + "Skriv en bokstav för att gissa ordet.");
            System.out.println("Antal gissningar du gjort: " + gissningar);
            gissningar++;
            guess = input.next();

            if(guess.length()==1) {
                unknownLetters.remove(Character.valueOf(guess.charAt(0)));
                showWord = pickWord;
                for(Character c : unknownLetters)
                    showWord=showWord.replaceAll(c.toString(), "_");
            }

        }

        System.out.println("You won! Tries needed: "+gissningar);

    }
}
```

Documentation of java naming convention: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: Wow, thanks alot man, really appreciate the help, thanks a bunch, anyway, how would I go and do so if I guess until this in the word testing: T _ STING, would it be possible to guess the whole word? Would I just do a if statement for that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to test for the completion of the word, you can do `if(showWord.equals(pickWord)) break;` to leave the `while` loop in that case. I'll add that to the answer ;)

Comment: No what I mean is like if the word is testing right now, and you guess testing, it will only take in the first t, how would you go to do so you can for example guess the whole word if you think you know what the word is?

Comment: This is a matter of how to interact with the user. If you let the user decide to either type in the whole word, or a single letter, you could test for the input size. If it is larger than 1, the user is obviously trying to guess the whole word. You could then do `if(guess.equalsIgnoreCase(pickWord)) break;`.

Comment: Okay, but where do i put the guess statement? Cause atm there is nothing called guess

Comment: And at the moment in your code, I dont know what the input is in the do loop? So I am not sure how to make it work with if statements (note im very new to this)

Comment: I reorganized the while loop a bit, to get rid of the not-so-nice "break out of the endless loop" thing. The while condition now clearly states the condition of staying in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not printing the previous guess in the `if-else` below. You either print the current guess if its present, or an underscore(_) and thus, the previous guess is not visible.

```
if (guess.equals(splitword[y])) {
    System.out.print(guess);
} else {
    System.out.print(" _ ");
}
```

You need to add an additional check to print the previous guess value, if it already exists. And for that you need an additional array which holds the previous guess or the string with guess filled.